# named pipes permission bits

Tags: c, unix, named-pipes

I am writing a simple C program to exchange messages
through named pipes on linux. The problem is I have
to run it as superuser to make it work, otherwise i get:
"Permission denied" error.
Write permission on the directory is granted:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 alpa alpa  4096 26 giu 17.24 .
```

Umask should be ok:

```
$ umask
0022
```

The pipe file is actually created, but with **wrong** permissions bits:

```
$ ls -l | grep fifo.fifo
pr----x--t 1 alpa alpa     0 26 giu 17.29 fifo.fifo
```

So when I try to open it for reading or writing the
open() system call fails.

Here is the code:

```
...
if(mkfifo(pathname, perms) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
  return NULL;
if(chmod(pathname, perms) == -1)
    return NULL;
...
fifo->fd[0]= open(fifo->pathname, O_RDONLY);
 if(fifo->fd[0] == -1){
fifo_delete(&fifo);
  return NULL;
...
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the value of `perms` that you are passing?

Comment: fifo=fifo_make("./fifo.fifo", 2, 666, 'r')
the value is 666

Comment: That 666 is decimal.  You want 0666.

Comment: the sticky bit (`t`) indicates that then number not being octal is the most likeliest reason for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value that you are passing is decimal `666`, which corresponds to octal `01232` (`01210` after applying `~umask`).

You should be passing either `0666`, or decimal `438`.

Comment: @alpa make sure to choose this answer as the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this because you are creating a fifo read-only? I don't see what are the parameters to mkfifo call in your snippet. But what 'man 3 mkfifo' says is:

> It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way: the
>   permissions of the created file are (mode & ~umask).

So make sure the mode is correct as the umask is only a limiting factor here.

Comment: The mode is 666 and umask 022

Comment: hm.... works for me ;) what happens if you create the pipe with mkfifo in command line? Have you tried fixing the perms to be 0666 and not 666? Looks like this is the problem especially by looking at the weird permissions you got there for that fifo...